# ImageMagick error: no decode delegate

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert an image with imagemagick, but I'm getting this error:

> convert: no decode delegate for this image format
>   `/tmp/magick-XXITXcTr' @ constitute.c/ReadImage/503.

I'm doing this:

```
convert http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/12003462-2669.jpg -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -matte -fill none -fuzz 7% -draw 'matte 1,1 floodfill' -shave 1x1 /myimagefolder/iphone.png
```

I have the following delegates:

> DELEGATES     bzlib fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng jp2 lcms openexr
>   png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: The url for the image from your repost returns a 404? You are trying to load an image that does not exist and then the temp file is probably empty and ImageMagick will return an error.

Comment: Argh! Thanks for noticing. Didn't expect those images to ever really be removed over there.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the image you are trying to download no longer exists and returns a 404. ImageMagick creates a temporary file before it downloads the image. But this file will remain empty because the download fails for this image. ImageMagick will try to read the image but fails because it cannot handle empty files.